# Possible deep change warning in vee validate 4 when using custom component

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vee-validate

I have 2 custom components, namely a select and a text field. The idea is to add or remove rows of fields dynamically. Now, when I add/remove a new row or when I change values in either select or text field, I see warnings in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Detected a possible deep change on field `value` ref, for nested changes please either set the entire ref value or use `setValue` or `handleChange`.
```

**Select component**

```
<template>
  <v-select v-model="value" :name="name" :error-messages="errorMessage" hide-details="auto">
    <!-- @vue-skip -->
    <template v-for="(_, slotName) in $slots" #[slotName]="slotData">
      <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData" />
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

const { value, errorMessage } = useField(() => props.name)
const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
})

</script>
```

**Text field component**

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="value" :name="name" :error-messages="errorMessage" hide-details="auto">
    <!-- @vue-skip -->
    <template v-for="(_, slotName) in $slots" #[slotName]="slotData">
      <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData" />
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

const { value, errorMessage } = useField(() => props.name)
const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
})

</script>
```

**Rendering of the rows**

```
 <form>
    <v-row v-for="(field, idx) in fields" :key="field.key" dense>
      <v-col :cols="field.value.boxShortName === 'custombox' ? 2 : 7">
        <custom-select
          :name="`boxes[${idx}]`"
          label="Box Type"
          :items="props.boxOptions"
          density="compact"
          return-object
        />
      </v-col>

      <!-- ... more fields -->

      <v-col :cols="field.value.boxShortName === 'custombox' ? 2 : 3">
        <custom-text-field
          :name="`boxes[${idx}].weight`"
          label="Wt"
          suffix="lbs"
          density="compact"
        />
      </v-col>
 <form>
```

**Script Snippet for the rendering**

```
const parcelBoxFormValidation = Yup.object({
  boxes: Yup.array(
    Yup.object({
      length: Yup
        .number()
        .transform((value, originalValue) => {
          return (originalValue === '' ? undefined : value)
        })
        .typeError('Must be a number')
        .min(1, 'Min length is 1 inch')
        .required('Required'),
      breadth: Yup
        .number()
        .transform((value, originalValue) => {
          return (originalValue === '' ? undefined : value)
        })
        .typeError('Must be a number')
        .min(1, 'Min breadth is 1 inch')
        .required('Required'),
      height: Yup
        .number()
        .transform((value, originalValue) => {
          return (originalValue === '' ? undefined : value)
        })
        .typeError('Must be a number')
        .min(1, 'Min height is 1 inch')
        .required('Required'),
      weight: Yup
        .number()
        .transform((value, originalValue) => {
          return (originalValue === '' ? undefined : value)
        })
        .typeError('Must be a number')
        .min(1, 'Min weight is 1 lb')
        .required('Required')
    })
  )
})

const { meta, resetForm, values } = useForm({
  validationSchema: parcelBoxFormValidation,
  initialValues: {
    boxes: []
  } as any
})

const { remove: removeBox, insert: insertBox, fields }: any = useFieldArray('boxes')

onMounted(() => {
  boxRecommendation()
})

const boxRecommendation = () => {
  resetForm({
    values: {
      boxes: [...props.boxOptions]
    }
  })
}

const addNewRow = async (idx: number) => {
  insertBox(idx + 1, props.boxOptions[props.boxOptions.length - 1])
}

const removeRow = async (idx: number) => {
  removeBox(idx)
}
```

**Box options prop value example**

```
 {
    title: 'Test Box',
    boxShortName: 'testbox',
    length: '12',
    breadth: '10',
    height: '6',
    weight: '5'
  },
  {
    title: 'Custom Box',
    boxShortName: 'custombox',
    length: '',
    breadth: '',
    height: '',
    weight: ''
  }
```

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this problem. I think this warning is strange because vue3 allows 'mutable' updates.